# Fastest way to convert videos to mp4

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, html5-video

Actually my conversion script for videos is using the [PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) package :

```
$ffmpeg   = FFMpeg::create(
                [
                    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => getenv('FFMPEG_PATH').'/ffmpeg',
                    'ffprobe.binaries' => getenv('FFMPEG_PATH').'/ffprobe',
                    'timeout'          => 3600,
                    'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,
                ]
            );
            $video = $ffmpeg->open($original_path_here);
            $format = new X264();
            $format->setAudioCodec('libmp3lame');
            $video->save($format, $converted_path_here);
```

But the conversion is quite long for each (less than 1 minute) video. Is there any way to improve the conversion time ?

Comment: Maybe php is not the best for that. And better hardware makes always things faster.

Comment: Apparently this PHP wrapper utilizes the `ffmpeg` binary. It is not possible to provide any practical suggestions without knowing the actual command passed to the `ffmpeg` binary and the resulting console output/log that the binary produces.

Comment: You were right. And with this package, we can not add more options to ffmpeg basic command..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the package does not allow to modify more options to ffmpeg command (in order to get a faster video conversion).

Then I decided to simply convert videos with the following PHP line :

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $original_path_here -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -profile:v baseline $converted_path_here");
```